# What movie/episode had a character get electric power from train track with a glowing finger?

Tags: story-identification

All I remember from a TV show I partly saw around 1970 is a character touching an electric third rail on train or subway tracks, absorbing electric power, and getting a glowing finger.  Not sure whether it was a villain or hero, or even whether it was a movie or series episode, looking for any information that may help me track down so I can watch in full now that I have a longer attention span, thanks.

Updates after initial replies: It was live action, not cartoon.  Based on how little I remember and my age I expect I saw it on TV in late 1960s or maybe early 1970s, probably not as late as 1979 although otherwise *The Power Within* (Chris gets electric powers from a lightning strike that need to be recharged) looks plausible, I'll check that out just in case.  I also looked for electricity manipulation [here](https://powerlisting.fandom.com/wiki/Electricity_Manipulation).  In that time frame, I saw most TV movies on "(some day) Night at the Movies" or "Creature (Double?) Feature".  I also checked TV episode guides for *Outer Limits*, *The Twilight Zone*, *My Favorite Martian*, and *Six Million Dollar Man*, but didn't see any obvious matches there.

Another update: Watched *The Power Within* on youtube, I had seen it when it came out but didn't remember title or details, not an exact match for visual (glowing body including hands but not specifically finger, recharge from a body enclosure not third rail) or timeframe, however I haven't found anything closer so suspect I may just be mixing elements from it with some unrelated earlier childhood memories (like getting warned about the NYC subway 3rd rail as a toddler).

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: *The Power Within* sounds vaguely right, but no train tracks or glowing finger that I can find.

Comment: Is this live action or cartoon? If it was being broadcast, do you remember the time of day?

Comment: Try [Misfits of Science (1985) TV Series](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088568/). Character Johnny B can absorb electricity and redirect it. Glowing hands etc. etc. but I could not find evidence of a train or train tracks... [sample YouTube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-0PH8o2XW8)

Comment: Thanks Valorum, FuzzyBoots, littlecoder, Adam for the quick and helpful replies!  Added updates to description.

Comment: Ah, the 1970s. “Hey kids, try touching the third rail! You never know what magical things might happen!”